# Test for closing TD tag with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document where some nodes contain HTML tables. I need to output that data as plain text and I'm trying to detect the closing TD tags so I can replace them with a tab instead.

Right now I tried using:

```
<xsl:when test="contains($text, '&lt;/td&gt;')">
<xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
```

That is not working however. Does anyone have a quick sample of the code I need to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, XSLT can't detect or replace opening/closing tags. XSLT works on a node tree, which is produced by parsing the tag markup. So you'll need to define your problem in terms of the td *elements*, text nodes, etc. of the input, not in terms of tags.

(If you really need to operate on the tags of the XML document, then you need to use a non-XML tool.)

For example, you might decide that you want to replace each `<td>` element with its text content followed by a tab. In that case, you could have a template like

```
<!-- match any td element -->
<xsl:template match="td">
  <!-- output the contents, recursively transforming them if necessary -->
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  <!-- output a tab character -->
  <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I gave that a shot and it did not change anything. I'm not sure what I am missing. The structure is like this

<text>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table
</text>

Comment: @CoreyT: without more context, I don't think I can help you. Can you edit your question to show more of the template structure of the stylesheet? What templates do you have (matching what patterns)?